Classic Regex, Is there a way to capture lines starting with `> >` and `> ` separately into different groups?
Obsidian to Anki has one of the most horrifying regex setup I have seen.
It involves the idea of capturing a whole segment of text that will be used for flashcard, then regexing inside it for questions (first capture group) and answers (second capture group).
Examples:
^(.*[^\n:]{1}):{2}([^\n:]{1}.*) (RemNote single line style)
^Q: ((?:.+\n)*)\n*A: (.+(?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))*) (Question answer style)
I want to do this for a bunch of notes that are setup with a lot of callouts, they look like this:
> [!PDF|] [[James W. Kurose, Keith W. Ross - Computer Networking.pdf#page=296&selection=32,0,33,25|James W. Kurose, Keith W. Ross - Computer Networking, p.296]]
>
> > Describe why an application developer might choose to run an application over UDP rather than TCP.
> 
> An application developer may not want its application to use TCP’s congestion control, which can throttle the application’s sending rate at times of congestion. Often, designers of IP blah blah.


I want to capture ALL lines starting with > > as question and ALL lines starting with > as answer. First and second capture groups in regex, specifically. Only it seems the presence of > in first and second capture group causes a mess because regex barely has negative matching?
I tried a lot of things including [^ >] after first capture group and (?! >) but it doesn't seem to work.
Further clarification:

There are no lines without >.
Both lines > > and > can occur more than once, but they can't appear out of order. > > always comes before >.
an example of ideal Capture outcome would be:

Describe why an application developer might choose to run an application over UDP rather than TCP. (First Capture group)

An application developer may not want its application to use TCP’s congestion control, which can throttle the application’s sending rate at times of congestion. Often, designers of IP blah blah. (Second capture group.)



With PCRE, you could do /^> > ([\s\S]*?)^>\s*^> ([\s\S]*)/m DEMO

Try it like this ^(> >.*(?:\n> >.*)*)(?:\n>\s*)*\n> ([^>\s].*(?:\n> [^>\s].*)*) https://regex101.com/r/y7DyrD/1

Or ^(> >.*)\n> \n(>.*) https://regex101.com/r/kqv12u/1

@VvdL: Rather than the specific > \n(>.*) (which will break on Windows) you can use >\s+> since \s matches all vertical and horizontal white space including \r\n on Windows...

All of these suggestions are very good but the central problem of not being able to capture ALL lines with > > remains, basically, add another line that starts with > > below the > > and see if it still works, and likewise with >.

O.K.: /^> > ([\s\S]*?)^>\s*^> ([\s\S]*?)(?:^\s*$|\z)/m DEMO

@CrimsonCrusader Can you update your question with an example of what should and should not be matched? Also, can > > occur only once on 1 line before matching > and can that line with a  single > also occur only once? Are there also lines without > ?

@Thefourthbird Here you go, I hope it answers your questions.

@CrimsonCrusader This would match 2 capture groups when there are only single lines ^> > (.*)(?:\n>\s*)*\n> ([^>\s].*) https://regex101.com/r/PbDlZW/1 If you want multiple lines that have the same pattern at the start, you can use ^> > (.*(?:\n> > [^>\s].*)*)(?:\n>\s*)*\n> (.*(?:\n> [^>\s].*)*) but note that you can not skip parts in a single regex match so the > and > >  will be there in the next lines https://regex101.com/r/554de3/1

This fits my needs, thanks. I will figure out a way to edit out the > > parts in anki. Note to self: don't shitpost in regex101 links.

If you want to match one or more lines that start with > >  and one or more lines that start with >  then you could start the first and second capture group after those matches.
But note that in a single regex match you can not skip a part. So if you are repeatedly matching lines with the same starting pattern like < <  or <  inside a capture group, that starting pattern will be part of the capture group value.
After matching > >  or >  you can match a single non whitespace character with [^>\s] to make sure that you can not match > > >
^> > (.*(?:\n> > [^>\s].*)*)(?:\n>\s*)*\n> (.*(?:\n> [^>\s].*)*)

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
> >  Match literally
( Capture group 1

.* Match the rest of the line
(?: Non capture group

\n> >  Match a newline and then > > 
[^>\s] Match a single non whitespace character other than >
.* Match the rest of the line


)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it


) Close group 1
(?:\n>\s*)* Optionally repeat matching a newline followed by > and optional whitespace chars
\n>  Match a newline and then > 
( Capture group 2

.* Match the rest of the line
(?:\n> [^>\s].*)* Optionally repeat matching a newline followed by <  and a non whitespace character other than > followed by the rest of the line


) Close group 2

See a regex demo

Having 2 separate parts in the capture group values, if possible you might do a second replacement over the capture group values removing the starting pattern with ^(?:> )+
See a regex demo for the replacements.
